# foreach loop not working - not joined with if statement

Tags: angularjs, foreach

Foreach loop not working.

I found this while debugging, it is not joining if statement, I tried 2 variants:

**First variant :**

```
$scope.feed.forEach(function (checkitem){
    if (checkitem.IsRead == false) {
        $scope.myObj = {
             "color": "white",
             "background-color": "coral"
           }
        }
    });
```

**And the second variant:**

```
angular.forEach(checkItem, function (value, key) {
            if (value.IsRead == false) {
                $scope.myObj = {
                    "color": "white",
                    "background-color": "coral"
                }
            }
        });
```

Both of them are not working.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? you have syntax error on this  $scope.myObj = {
             color": "white", change to "color": "white",

Comment: can you post your variable that is an array you are trying to iterate through?

Comment: @Harry, it didn't join if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is your array variable, presumably,

```
$scope.feed = [{isRead: true}];
$scope.feed.forEach(function (checkitem){
    if (checkitem.IsRead == false) {
        $scope.myObj = {
             "color": "white",
             "background-color": "coral"
           }
        }
    });
```

above will work, but you need to make sure that your array is in order.

Answer (score 0):

in angular.foreach code seems you have passed wrong object. If you want to loop through $scope.feed object, pass it there instead of "checkItem".